# efficiently convert yyyymmdd in delimited files

Tags: python, linux, awk

I have large dat file (zipped) in pipe delimited format. The 6th column has date format yyyymmdd, which needs to be converted to yyyy-mm-dd, so that I can use bcp utility to load to a sql server.

The content of the file looks like (5.26million rows, uncompressed about 0.46G)

```
AA|AA|AAA|AAAAA|AAAA|20191001|AA|...
BB|BB|BBB|BBBBB|BBBB|20191001|BB|...
```

My question is why the command line awk is slower than the python script. Is there a faster way to do it in the command line with awk or sed? There are a total 14 columns per line. The python code split the line and stops at the 6th column. This may contribute to the difference. But columns after 6th are not much longer in general.

```
]$ time unzip -p /aa/bb/somedata.zip | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} { $6=substr($6,1,4) "-" substr($6,5,2) "-" substr($6,7,2);} 1' > data1.DAT
real 0m19.141s
user 0m20.219s

]$ time ~/test.py;
real 0m12.393s
user 0m10.458s

]$ time unzip -p /aa/bb/somedata.zip > data2.DAT
real 0m1.952s
user 0m1.619s
```

The python code looks like:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('/aa/bb/somedata.zip', 'r') as zf:
    with zf.open(somedata.DAT, 'r') as f, open('/aa/bb/data2bcp.DAT', 'w') as wf:
        for line in TextIOWrapper(f):
            toks = line.split('|', 6)
            toks[5] = toks[5][0:4] +'-' + toks[5][4:6] + '-' + toks[5][6:8]
            wf.write('|'.join(toks))
```

After I remove the limit on split the run time of python is not much different

```
toks = line.split('|')

] $ time ~/test.py;
real 0m13.006s
user 0m12.164s
```

Comment: Doesn't `bcp` have some functionality to deal with strings and dates?

Comment: if the target column is defined as date, then it has to be yyyy-mm-dd. If the target column is defined as smalldatetime, yyyymmdd will work

Comment: Did you run your tests more than 1 time? (Are you aware of the effects of OS level file caching on such tests?). Good luck.

Comment: Also, `awk` doesn't do well with reordering data in each record (it is time consuming, as you have found out). While it may not work for your production problem, as a test, you could move your `substr` commands to add a new column at the end of the line (and skip the original column in your `bcp.fmt` file). This might speed up the process somewhat.ALSO, Are you using reasonable hardware? I'm surprized at these times for a sub GB sized file. Good luck.

Comment: test done multiple times on the same file, should not be impacted by caching. server is about 4 years old, but still decent, HP ProLiant 380p Gen8, 20 core 128G RAM. But in this case, multiple core, big RAM prob don't help.

Answer (score 1):

You may try below if you have `gawk`, compare performance of `substr()` and `gensub()` 
with your large dataset

```
$ cat infile
AA|AA|AAA|AAAAA|AAAA|20191001|AA|...
BB|BB|BBB|BBBBB|BBBB|20191001|BB|...   

$ awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{$6=gensub(/(....)(..)(..)/,"\\1-\\2-\\3","",$6)}1' infile
AA|AA|AAA|AAAAA|AAAA|2019-10-01|AA|...
BB|BB|BBB|BBBBB|BBBB|2019-10-01|BB|...
```

Comment: gawk runs similar, one test 18.951s, another one 20.473. Switched to gensub, it is 2-3 seconds slower. software maybe old, but shouldn't be that different in terms of this job. awk/gawk both 3.1.7 version